# Ruby (bundler) How to automatically require Pry

Tags: ruby, bundler, pry, binding.pry

Given a Gemfile containing:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'pry'
```

And a ruby file containing:

```
require 'bundler/setup'

# NOT using this line:
# require 'pry'

binding.pry
```

I am getting this error:

`enter code here`undefined method `pry' for #<Binding:0x00007f846f053bb0> (NoMethodError)`

I know I can easily add `require 'pry'` in my file, but I really dont want to do that whenever I debug a file.

Also, I would intuitively believe that `bundler/setup` would autorequire my rubygems defined in the Gemfile.

Can you explain how I can autorequire the file in my Gemfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use `Bundler.require(:default)` after `require 'bundler/setup'` - since the latter just sets up the load path. See http://bundler.io/v1.16/guides/bundler_setup.html.

Comment: Thanks for precise, simple answer!